# Is there any dedicated IR receiver IC with atleast 5 output pins

Tags: microcontroller, infrared, remote-control, ir-receiver

I want  to know if there is any IC available that can decode an IR remote to its different pinouts  or I have only option to program a microcontroller to achieve it.

Comment: What do you mean by "different pinouts? Can you clarify what do you mean? Surely some IR decoder chips exist or at least have existed in the past, but they might have been preprogrammed MCUs anyway.

Comment: If you mean "five output pins" that's vastly different than "five pinouts".  A chip's "pinout" is the **pattern** of pin assignments -- i.e., what's pin 1, what's pin 2, etc.  Having the same chip function with different pinouts -- at least in the same sized package -- is not at all common.

Comment: why do you require a 5 pin configuration?

Comment: @TimWescott Yes you are right. I mean 5 output pins. Correcting my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemingly you expect something which has 5 separate outputs which can be activated one at a time by pressing buttons 1...5 on an IR remote controller.

The others have tried to say that this is possible, in theory such IC can exist. But you must have a remote controller designed just for that IC. Generally the codes used in remote control systems are complex and everyone is different. The code contains some identification of "who is sending", the wrong sender is ignored. Then there's the code of the wanted function, maybe only the number of the pressed button and finally some calculated redundancy data to detect and fix transmission errors. Everything can be encrypted to make 3rd party devices more difficult to make. Big entertainment electronics manufacturers such as Sony have licensed their coding systems to others. They can bill say $10000,- for the code details.

You may find an IR receiver which generates computer compatible raw serial data output from the voltage that an IR photodiode catches. But a programmed computer (=microcontroller) is needed to decode the raw data and launch the wanted operations. There's numerous "IR remote decoder" projects presented in the web. Search for them.

Finally some preprogrammed chips to decode some known IR remote coding exists. Here's a link to one story of one chip https://www.voti.nl/ir-3/index_1.html No idea is it really available and does it work. I wouldn't believe such articles if there's no direct manufacture's data available which shows the system is properly constructed.

Also chips for remote controllers exist. Again: No idea of the availability https://www.infraredremote.com/RS117.htm

Comment: Yes ir3. This is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is such a wide range of needs for IR remote control that there are very few or probably zero devices that receive and decode IR remote control signals.

You will need to do it with a microcontroller.

Do you have an IR transmitter?